# How to find the relevant header file?

Tags: header-files, c++builder

In C++Builder 10.3 I have a code with `fopen()` function. I know that this function is declared in `stdio.h`. In my code this header is not included explicitly but, I guess implicitly in `Vcl.h`. Trying to confirm it I opened `Vcl.h` but found no `stdio.h` there. Instead I found many other header files. Is there a way to dig out where `stdio.h` file is hidden?

Comment: It should be in the include directory of your installation. If you get an error message, you know that *stdio.h* is not included by *vcl.h*. Otherwise it probably is.

Comment: Why not use borland/embarcadero/VCL native `FileOpen,FileSeek,FileRead,FileWrite,FileClose` binary file access? Also the `fopen` in question can be also in different header than `stdio`... Anyway in the end it would use some stuff from `windows.h` include tree as file access is OS function. In case of different OS the header will be different.

Comment: @Spektre: `fopen` is in `stdio.h` or `cstdio`. It should not be (and is not) defined in another header: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen . That is not dependent on the OS. The **implementation** is OS-dependent, but that is irrelevant. But the functions you mention, like `FileOpen` are **not VCL**, they are Windows-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to problems with new compiler first make sure that you use "classic Borland compiler". Then write `fopen` in text editor. Press `CRTL` + left click on `fopen` and it will open `stdio.h`. In my case it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\include\windows\crtl folder.

Comment: May you say a few words about problems with the new compiler? I heard nothing about that. I would clarify my original question. I am not looking for where 'stdio.h' is located on my drive. I am trying to figure out where the reference to 'stdio.h' is hidden in 'vcl.h'.

Comment: Then your question needs to be corrected. New compiler has many problems with IDE, mostly with Intellisense, code completion etc. Fixes are expected with 10.3.2 version.

Comment: @maksim: then your question is not worded correctly. I also thought you were trying to find out where stdio.h is on your file system.